# drag and drop using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

i have two lists which are based on jquery, sample is [here](http://devheart.org/examples/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/2-saving-and-loading-items/index.html) i need exactly same functionality but with slightchanges like follows:

as per the above when i click on `Get items` i get all the sortable items values but what i want is drag from List A and put them to List B and vise versa, if i click on get items i should get only sortable items on List B not from List A.

how to do this, can we customise the above jquery lib or is there any other even if they are in java script it is fine for me.

Please do help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done something similiar in the past, this is how I achieved it: http://jsfiddle.net/dazefs/vGYVX/

```
<div style="background-color:Gray">

<ul id="sortable">
    <li>
      <span style="background-color:yellow">
         Item 1
       </span>

     </li>
    <li>
     <span style="background-color:red">
       Item 2
     </span>

    </li>
    <li>
      <span style="background-color:green">
     Item 3
     </span>

  </li>
    <li>
    <span style="background-color:Blue">
           Item 4
     </span>
     </li>
   </ul>

<ul id="sortable2" style="width:60%">
<li>
    <span style="background-color:yellow">
        Item 5
    </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <span style="background-color:red">
        Item 6
    </span>
</li>
    <li>
    <span style="background-color:green">
        Item 7
    </span>
   </li>
    <li>
       <span style="background-color:Blue">
          Item 8
       </span>
   </li>
</ul>

 </div>
```

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable2, #sortable",
        receive: function (event, ui) {
             alert('item has been sorted');
         }
    });

    //})
});
```

**To achieve with 3 tile groups:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dazefs/XRdz6/

http://jsfiddle.net/dazefs/vGYVX/

You will have to modify this implementation slightly to incorporate getting items after "GetItems" is clicked.

Comment: thanks for the post, this is what i wanted, but how to get the items available which are moved from List A to List B(Only on list B)?

Comment: @Anto - you will have to keep a collection of items that can be moved, this could be handled using an array. Then in the sortable receive function you could check if the item selected can be moved, if not display an error.

Comment: there is no restriction to drag an item from one list or another, `at the end when the user clicks on save(get items) i have to save all the items available at List B(which are moved from List A.) as of you sample you have given` `span`, can we give id and value for the span?, Please provide me with sample. Please don't mind