# How to drag row from one table to another table in jsp

Tags: jsp, drag-and-drop, row

How to drag row from one table to another table in jsp?

Comment: I think you can use, drag and drop feature of HTML 5. Things can  be sorted just using HTML 5.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp) is way forward to achieve [drag-drop](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp) using javascript, here are some links to help you get started with it:

1. [HTML5 Drag-drop Basics](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)
2. [HTML5 drag-drop demo](http://html5demos.com/drag)

But if you don't want to use it then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12671737/1761033) might help you. The answer also includes a jsfiddle (working examples) link at the end, which you can play with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript library to implement it. See [this](http://www.isocra.com/2007/07/dragging-and-dropping-table-rows-in-javascript/)